# How to store tamarind paste?

Tags: storage-method, spices, thai-cuisine

I bought some tamarind paste the other day, and I am wondering how should I store it once opened, as the package does not say anything special. Should I put it in the fridge? Store it in an airtight container? Freeze it (as I am probably not going to use it very often)?

How long will it last?

Comment: rubbery block with seeds? that just needs plastic film around and lasts years. Anything more processed with water decreases shelf-life. I have had quite runny 'paste' that I could have frozen but used up quickly to replace with better quality. I sub tamarind for other tart ingr. regularly so get thru it quicker (Margaritas etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My tub of tamarind paste says store in a cool dry place. It should last up to its use by date (2 years in my case), provided it doesn't grow mould.

Comment: Mould, the reason I put most things in the fridge even if they say "cool dry place". I've had some occasional bad luck.

Answer (score 6):

I am a south Indian who use tamarind in my daily cooking. As previously answered a block of tamarind can be stored wrapped at room temperature. but anything processed like a paste or juice should be refrigerated after opening.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this purveyor](http://www.hellotrade.com/abc-international-india/tamarind-paste.html), you can store it under "ambient conditions" (which is industry speak for essentially room temperature) for about six months to one year.  Of course, I would use an airtight container.