# What to do with insoluble tamarind parts found in a paste pouch, to prevent them appearing in dishes

Tags: indian-cuisine, korean-cuisine, tamarind

When I use tamarind paste, which I buy in a pack that looks like this, ..

[image: tamarind paste]

.. I end up with seeds (which I can remove), with paste (which I can dissolve on low heat), but also with what seems like skin, and a few fibrous parts.

[image: tamarind in recipe]

I never recall seeing those part in restaurant dishes.

What am I doing wrong? Should I scoop out these parts one by one. Should the paste really pass by a blender/kitchen machine first? Will an extended duration on low heat eventually dissolve them?

##### Other Tamarind questions on cooking.SE

- [How to store tamarind paste?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/30048/85398)
- [How do I use whole fresh tamarind?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/13444/85398)
- [Where do I find the fruit tamarind?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/45547/85398)
- [How do I use tamarind powder?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/46252/85398)
- [What can we do if we accidentally buy tamarind puree instead of paste?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/73338/85398)
- [Can you eat the seeds of Tamarind if you roast them or boil them?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/42288/85398)

Comment: I didn't even know you could buy tamarind paste. I have only seen it fresh in the pods.

Comment: You can also get it in jars; they've done all the hard work for you;)

Comment: You can get it in blocks, paste (with salt) and fresh, and the jarred stuff is 'different' from the block stuff

Comment: @JourneymanGeekOnStrike Somebody should ask a question asking to show us what these variations look like, and perhaps identify the extra ingredients in each variation, if any.

Comment: I suspect that the "skin" you're talking about is the membrane that surrounds the seeds (separating it from the pulp) in the tamarind fruit.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Perhaps. In any case, it may be best to simply refer to them as 'insoluble parts'. I updated the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove the amount of tamarind you want to use from package.  Place in a bowl.  Add some water or other liquid...often hot to better dissolve the tamarind.  Let soak a bit.  Stir and mash with spoon or fork.  Place all of that in a strainer over a bowl or the pot in which it will go.  Use a spoon to force as much pulp and liquid as possible through the strainer.  Discard the seeds and "skin" or pods.

Comment: Perfect. Quick sequel question to avoid minuscule questions: tamarind arrives in a non-hermetically sealed package. Hence it can remain in the pantry. Is that accurate?

Comment: I keep mine in the refrigerator.   I think we have a question on tamarind pulp storage on the site.  You can use the search bar.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Added some links.

Comment: Its acidic and generally dosen't spoil. We just dump it into a large glass screw top bottle and it lasts quite a while

Comment: @JourneymanGeekOnStrike You're presumably talking about a version of tamarind that's different from the one pictured; no? This version is quite solid, requiring some force to cut it.

Comment: actually very similar , its break-up-able by hand